# Handle Eigen::Index conversion warning

Tags: c++, eigen

The following code gives me the warning (using VS 2019)

```
void test(int a, int b){
   /* Some code */
}

Eigen::MatrixXd foo = Eigen::MatrixXd::Ones(8, 10);
test(6, foo.rows());
```

```
warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'Eigen::Index' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

Rather than disabling the warning, how can I 'properly convert' `Eigen::Index` to an `int` or `const int`

Comment: Add an explicit cast?

Comment: void test(const int a, const Eigen::Index& b). Obviously an int is not equal to Eigen::Index (probably that's a long or unsigned long). Be precise is all I can say

Comment: @PepijnKramer Well yeah sure, I could be precise about it but then the function `test` is used again somewhere else where I wont pass a `Eigen::Index` but an actual int?

Comment: Then make two overloads. Or if the actual /* some code */ bit is the same for both types make it a template function. E.g. template<typename T> test(const T& a, const T&b) { /* some code */ } (Try to avoid casts)

Comment: Converting `int` to `Eigen::Index` should never raise a warning. So if you can just write `void test(int a, Eigen::Index b) {...}` you should not have any problems with converting to `b` (you may need to change types inside `test` and maybe pass `a` as `Eigen::Index` as well ...)

Comment: @PepijnKramer `Eigen::Index` defaults to `std::ptrdiff_t` so on 64bit architectures it is an `int64_t` (I would generally pass that by value and not by const reference)

Comment: @chtz no then a reference is not needed, a const would still be preferable